# SQL Server : view MUCH slower than same query by itself

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

From this SO answer a view should provide the same performance as using the same query directly.

[Is querying over a view slower than executing SQL directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630633/is-querying-over-a-view-slower-than-executing-sql-directly)

I have a view where this is not true.

This query targeting a view

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [Front].[vw_Details] k
WHERE 
    k.Id = 970435
```

Takes 10 seconds to complete. Copying the query from the view and adding `WHERE k.Id = 970435` to it completes in less than 1 second. The view is nothing special, 4 `LEFT JOIN`s, and a few `CASE` directives to clean up data.

How can I figure out what the problem is, or what do I need to complete this question with in order for this to be answerable?

**Update 1:**

- SQL Server Version: 12.0.4436.0
- Query plan for view: https://pastebin.com/RY40Ab0k
- Query plan for select: https://pastebin.com/gwahhgpu

Comment: Step #1 is the query plan. Performance many also depend on *where/how* this query is executed; plain SSMS queries likely promote through constant selection (which would not apply to a parameterized query or as a SP parameter). Constant selections can result in 'ridiculously different/better' plans.

Comment: Anyway, tldr: while MSSQL considers the SQL inside a view as part of the original query/plan, it does *not* guarantee the same plan selection as a verbatim copy of said view - which is where the different plans and performance profiles come from.

Comment: SQL version and query plans added

Comment: Search for 970435, which should show the 'issue'. In the fast/non-view case it is used in a seek (SeekPredicate).

Comment: Hmm, could you possibly spell it out for me. I do see that the executionplan for the view has "parameterized" paramaters, but I dont know why that is bad or what I should do about it.

Comment: If running queries directly from SSMS, the "parameterized" issue generally doesn't apply (note how it used the constant value in the parameter), which can also make queries there significantly different from code. However, the plan difference is still real. The fast query uses an *index seek* first, to select only rows with ID=970435. The slower query does not; the slow query 'gets most of the data' (doing much more IO and possibly expanding multiplicity) before using a predicate filter on the 'working set'. The 'visual' mode of the query plans is usually simpler to at-a-glance check :}

Comment: In this particular case, adding an index hint (or plan guide) *may* be appropriate. However, this may limit SQL Server's ability to choose a better query when *not* only looking a specific ID (or two). Another consideration, should be to ensure that the statistics are up to date.

Comment: @JensB, do you get a good plan if you specify a literal when querying the view (like you did the non-view query)?  `SELECT * FROM [Bospar].[Front].[vw_Kontakt_Detaljer] [k] WHERE [k].[Kontakt_sk]=970435`

Comment: That query plan does not reflect the posted view query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your query plan is no longer visible, but if you look in the plan, you will most likely see a triangle complaining about the cardinality estimation and/or implicite declaration. What it means is that you are joining tables in a way where your keys are hard to guess for the SQL engine.

It is instant when you run from a query directly, probably because it doesn't need to guess the size of your key is

For example:

```
k.Id = 970435
```

SQLSERVER already knows that it is looking for 970435  a 6 digit number.
It can eliminate all the key that doesn't start by 9 and doesn't have 6 digits. :)

However, in a view, it has to build the plan in a way to account for unknown. Because it doesn't know what kind of key it may hold.

See the  microsoft  for various example and scenario that may help you.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/query-processing-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

If you are always looking for an int, one work around is to force the type with a cast or convert clause. It's may cause performance penalty depending on your data, but it is a trick in the toolbox to tell sql to not attempt the query a plan as varchar(max) or something along that line.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  [Front].[vw_Details] k
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT,k.Id) = 970435
```

Comment: That worked. I still don't understand why. I'd think the query engine would already know it's dealing with an int, even in a view.

Answer (score 0):

use a stored procedure to return results.  stored procedures use indexes, whereas, views often don't

or

use a table function and query the table function